# How to know if a request is running from collection in test script?

Tags: javascript, postman

In postman test script, how do I know if request is running from collection or just from request?

Answer (score 3):

I parsed the Postman variables and found:

```
postman.__execution.cursor.length
```

Which is the number of request that the runner will run. If it is running from collection, "length" value is the number of request in collection.

Here is function :

```
function isRunningFromCollection(){
    return postman.__execution.cursor.length > 1;
}
```

Warning : Don't work for a collection of one request...